# Spring Data Neo4j 4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT OGM 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT NullPointerException

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

On the latest `Spring Data Neo4j 4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` and `OGM 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT` my tests failed with a following NPE(a few days ago everything worked fine and no single line of my code has not been changed):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neo4j.ogm.entity.io.EntityAccessManager.getRelationalReaders(EntityAccessManager.java:355)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.bothWayMappingRequired(EntityGraphMapper.java:893)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntityReferences(EntityGraphMapper.java:396)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:230)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.map(EntityGraphMapper.java:134)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:83)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:44)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.save(Neo4jSession.java:419)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedSessionCreator.java:133)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.save(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.SimpleGraphRepository.save(SimpleGraphRepository.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor60.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.decisionwanted.domain.dao.decision.CharacteristicOptionDaoImpl.createOrUpdate(CharacteristicOptionDaoImpl.java:44)
    at com.decisionwanted.domain.dao.decision.CharacteristicOptionDaoImpl.create(CharacteristicOptionDaoImpl.java:24)
    at com.decisionwanted.domain.DecisionCharacteristicTest.testDecisionCharacteristicOptions(DecisionCharacteristicTest.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

My code:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Characteristic extends Authorable {

    public final static String NODE_NAME = "Characteristic";

    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";
    private final static String DEFINED_BY = "DEFINED_BY";

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private Type type;

    private Mode mode;

    private boolean sortable;

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<CharacteristicOption> options = new HashSet<>();

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private CharacteristicGroup group;

    @Relationship(type = DEFINED_BY, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Decision owner;

    public Characteristic() {
    }

    public Characteristic(String name, String description, Type type, Mode mode, Decision owner, User author) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.type = type;
        this.mode = mode;
        this.owner = owner;
        setAuthor(author);
    }

    public Characteristic(String name, String description, Type type, Mode mode, Decision owner, User author, CharacteristicGroup group) {
        this(name, description, type, mode, owner, author);
        this.group = group;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Mode getMode() {
        return mode;
    }

    public void setMode(Mode mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    public boolean isSortable() {
        return sortable;
    }

    public void setSortable(boolean sortable) {
        this.sortable = sortable;
    }

    public Set<CharacteristicOption> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public void setOptions(Set<CharacteristicOption> options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    public boolean addOption(CharacteristicOption option) {
        return options.add(option);
    }

    public CharacteristicGroup getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(CharacteristicGroup group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public Decision getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(Decision owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public static enum Type {

        //@formatter:off
        BOOLEAN("Boolean"),
        INTEGER("Integer"),
        STRING("String");
        //@formatter:on

        private final String name;

        Type(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

    }

    public static enum Mode {

        //@formatter:off
        CHECKBOX("CheckBox"),
        SLIDER("Slider"),
        SELECTBOX("SelectBox"),
        RADIOGROUP("String");
        //@formatter:on

        private final String name;

        Mode(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

    }
}

@NodeEntity
public class CharacteristicOption extends BaseEntity {

    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private Object value;

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Characteristic characteristic;

    public CharacteristicOption() {
    }

    public CharacteristicOption(String name, String description, Object value, Characteristic characteristic) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.value = value;
        this.characteristic = characteristic;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Characteristic getCharacteristic() {
        return characteristic;
    }

    public void setCharacteristic(Characteristic characteristic) {
        this.characteristic = characteristic;
    }

}

@Override
public CharacteristicOption createOrUpdate(CharacteristicOption characteristicOption) {
    auditing(characteristicOption);

    return characteristicOptionRepository.save(characteristicOption);
}
```

What can be a reason of this issue and how to fix it ?

Comment: can you check that you are on the latest snapshot of both OGM and SDN? We had a build break yesterday and you might be using that version. You may just need to force an update of the latest snapshot. Check the spring and neo4j maven snapshot repos for the latest versions. if you still get the error please open a github issue.

Comment: @digx1 thanks for your answer. No luck.. I have update the repo with the same result so I have create a following github issue https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/254

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CharacteristicOption` class declares a field:

`private Object value;`

A recent commit to the 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT excluded `Object` and `Object[]` references as persistable properties. As a result the OGM tried to map the `value` property via a relationship, rather than as a simple node attribute.

This has been corrected in the latest snapshot build.